# How to set input value using downshift in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, downshift

I'm creating autocomplete input text box using downshiftjs. When the result of autocomplete is clicked, I can't set the input text.

**I'm creating the sample code** [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-villani-c56ul?file=/src/App.js)

The autocomplete is working:

[image]

And it's searchable:

[image]

When I click the item, I can't set the input box value with the item I clicked.

Comment: Have you take a look to the browser console log?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/wy3jv4lqvk

Comment: Thank you @YusufIbrahim, I'll try to explore the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mast define `itemToString` function in hook, because you use array of object as select items. And some fix in `<li>` markup.

Edited working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-kepler-4v42x?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hey Ilya, the sandbox link isn't working anymore

Comment: @Daksh Apparently I unintentionally deleted the previous working example. New working fork https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-noyce-6k6jn